# Program for basic arithmetic operations

Tags: python

[image: Click Here For Question]

This is how i have coded, but i am not able to get the result as i want

```
def arith():
    import random
    operators = ("+","*")

    for i in range(4):
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        y = random.randint(1,10)

        choose_operators = random.choice(operators)
        print (x,choose_operators,y)
        t1 = int(input("what is the answer:"))
        counter = 0
        if t1 == (x,operators,y):
            counter = counter + 1

            if counter > 3:
                print("Congratulations!")

            else:
                print("Please ask your teacher for help")
```

I get the result as

arith()

7 * 3

what is the answer:21

3 + 2

what is the answer:5

8 * 9

what is the answer:72

3 * 9

what is the answer:2

That's it!

How do i make it count the number of correct answers and print the command i have written ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The line `if t1 == x,operators,y` is not operating on `x` and `y`. The operator is the form of a string so it is checking if `t1` is equal to, for example: `(7, '*', 3)`. To actually do the operation you can use `eval()` Also, you need to fix some stuff in your code so it only checks `counter` after the `for` loop is finished.

```
def arith():
    import random
    operators = ("+","*")
    counter = 0


    for i in range(4):
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        y = random.randint(1,10)

        choose_operators = random.choice(operators)
        print (x,choose_operators,y)
        t1 = int(input("what is the answer:"))
        if t1 == eval(str(x) + choose_operators + str(y)):
            counter = counter + 1

    if counter > 3:
        print("Congratulations!")

    else:
        print("Please ask your teacher for help")
```